# Finding Laplace Transform from diagram

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

I have a diagram that looks like below:

[image]

First, I have attempted to express the diagram function regarding f(t) as below:

\begin{equation}
  f(t) =
    \begin{cases}
      t & \text{0 < t ≦ 1}\\
      2-t & \text{1 < t ≦ 3}\\
      t-4 & \text{3 < t ≦ 5}\\
      6-t & \text{5 < t ≦ 7}\\
      t-8 & \text{7 < t ≦ 8}\\
      0 & \text{t < 0, 8 < t}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

I am not certain about this, but I think it should make sense a little bit if we put the equation to the corresponding interval. Now I would like to find the following **Laplace Transform** based on the interval respectively:

\begin{equation}
  f_1(t) =
    \begin{cases}
      t & \text{0 < t ≦ 1}\\
      2-t & \text{1 < t ≦ 2}\\
      0 & \text{t < 0, t > 2}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  f_2(t) =
    \begin{cases}
      2-t & \text{2 < t ≦ 3}\\
      t-4 & \text{3 < t ≦ 4}\\
      0 & \text{t ≦ 2, t > 4}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  f(t) =
    \begin{cases}
      t & \text{0 < t ≦ 1}\\
      2-t & \text{1 < t ≦ 3}\\
      t-4 & \text{3 < t ≦ 5}\\
      6-t & \text{5 < t ≦ 7}\\
      t-8 & \text{7 < t ≦ 8}\\
      0 & \text{t < 0, 8 < t}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
(Note: the above equations are derived from the diagram that I see. Only the intervals are given in the case)

Based on the definition of Laplace Transform and its common formula sheet, the first Laplace transform I wrote like this:

\begin{equation}
  F_1(s) =
    \begin{cases}
      \mathscr{L}\{t\}=\int_{0}^{\infty}te^{-st}dt = \dfrac{1}{s^2} 
      & \text{0 ≦ t ≦ 1}\\
      \mathscr{L}\{2-t\}=\int_{0}^{\infty}(2-t)e^{-st}dt = \dfrac{2}{s} - \dfrac{1}{s^2} & \text{1 < t ≦ 2}\\
      0 & \text{t < 0, t > 2}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

However, my question is, does it make sense to simply add the equation above as the result of the Laplace transform like this:

\begin{equation}
  F_1(s) = \dfrac{2}{s}
\end{equation}

If this is incorrect, what could be the answer?

Please help me with this. Thank you for your advice and time!

Comment: Possible hint: peroidic functions and the Heaviside function. Thst should simplify things a little

Comment: $\int_0^1e^{-st}tdt+\int_1^3e^{-st}(2-t)dt+$ etc

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have looked up the Heaviside function, and it looks like I need to figure out the interval that makes the value of the given function 0 or 1 first. However, I am still confused about deriving the result.

Comment: Oh! It seems that I simply derive them from the definition of Laplace transform and change the interval of the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining

$$
\Lambda(t) = \cases{t, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0\lt t\le 1\\ 2-t, \ \ 1\lt t\le 2\\ 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{otherwise} }
$$

we have

$$
f(t) = \Lambda(t)-\Lambda(t-T)+\Lambda(t-2T)-\Lambda(t-3T)
$$

and thus

$$
\hat f(s) = (1-e^{-2s}+e^{-4s}-e^{-6s})\hat \Lambda(s)
$$

with

$$
\hat \Lambda(s) = \frac{e^{-2 s} \left(e^s-1\right)^2}{s^2}
$$

NOTE

$$
\Lambda(t) = t\left(\theta(t)-\theta(t-1)\right)+(2-t)\left(\theta(t-1)-\theta(t-2)\right)
$$

where $\theta(t)$ is the [heaviside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) unit step function. Here

$$
\int_0^{\infty} t\left(\theta(t)-\theta(t-1)\right)e^{-s t}dt = \int_0^{1} t e^{-s t}dt = \frac{1-e^{-s} (s+1)}{s^2}
$$

etc.  Also

$$
\int_0^{\infty}f(t-T)e^{-s t}dt = e^{-sT}\hat f(s)
$$

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. But this seems to differ from what I have calculated if I simply calculate $$ \int_0^{1}te^{-st}dt + \int_1^2(2-t)e^{-st}dt $$
Could you explain the process in detail?

Comment: Please- See attached note.

Comment: Thank you. I will spend some time digging into it. Looks like it is a bit beyond what I knew regarding step function.

Comment: Sir, I now understand the parts that you wrote in the "NOTE". Does the **T** you wrote to stand for $2 - t$ in the definition? Thank you for your help. Things are getting clear to me after delving into related topics about this.

Comment: $-T$ in $\Lambda(t-T)$ represents  advance in time of $\Lambda(t)$ graphics. In our case $T = 2$.

Comment: Thanks! That's awesome, your procedure is concise. I now finally understand what you mean.